# str_replace/nl2br not acting as expected

Tags: php

I'm having some weird difficulty with removing "\n"'s from data that is pulled from a database.

The data is an email and gets stored with \n's throughout it by the system that inputs it.

When I display it, I've tried to remove these \n's using the following:

```
$htmlbody = str_replace("\n", "", $message['htmlbody']);
```

or

```
nl2br($message['htmlbody']);
```

but both commands still return a string that is full of \n's.

The variable $message['htmlbody'] includes a string like `\n\n <div>\n Example Data \n </div>\n`, and this data remains the same after being passed through str_replace.

The data originally comes from a JSON webhook which has replaced all the newlines in an HTML email with \n's. I have control over the data being put into the database as well, and have tried using the above actions on the original data with the same result.

Any thoughts on what might cause this?

Cheers.

Comment: You do assign the result of `str_replace`, don't you?

Comment: Yeah. `$htmlbody = str_replace("\n","",$message['htmlbody']);` is used, and then at the moment i'm using `echo $htmlbody` to test it... a sample string is being output as `\n\n <div>\n                    bjhbkhbkbhkuubuhbhjbh\n </div>\n`

Comment: You realise you're missing the closing parenthesis in your `nl2br` example? (I imagine that's a typo *here*, rather than your problem, though).

Comment: Are ou sure that your line return are just \n and not \r\n ?

Comment: Yeah. No \r anywhere. This is the data that comes straight from the JSON response, and it only has \n's.

Comment: @DavidThomas - and thanks! Typo on here ;) Corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$message['htmlbody'] = str_replace("\n", "", $message['htmlbody']);
```

If the string you try to modify have `\n` **displayed**, and not interpreted as a new line, use :

```
$message['htmlbody'] = str_replace("\\n", "", $message['htmlbody']);
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's pretty much what I have at the moment. I tried it for the hell of it and still having the same issue. Output still includes \n's: `\n\n <div>\n bjhbkhbkbhkuubuhbhjbh\n </div>\n`

Comment: can you edit your post and copy a bit more of your code please

Comment: And it's as simple as that - thank you so much! 

I would have thought that the fact that PHP was displaying \n in database and on the page would meant it didn't interpret it. Obviously not the case!

Answer (score 1):

Found this in a google search

```
$message = preg_replace("/\n|\r/", " ", $message['htmlbody']);
```

Which will replace newlines with whitespace.

Comment: your solution will replace "\r\n" chars (windows carriage return line feed) with two spaces...

Comment: Correct me if I am reading it wrong, but this should replace line feeds OR carriage returns with a single space. The space is trivial to remove, but is probably useful for most situations. EDIT: I see what you are saying. Hmmm.

Comment: watch my answer, i think is better to replace first the \r\n and than the rest!

Answer (score 1):

to replace first \r\n then \r and then \n use this:

```
 $message['htmlbody'] = preg_replace(array("/\r\n/", "/\r/", "/\n/"), array(' ',' ', ' '), $message['htmlbody']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing `$message` through `stripslashes`. It is possible that you have \\n\\r, that is double slashes which prevent correct escaping...

```
$message['htmlbody'] = nl2br(stripslashes($message['htmlbody']))
```